# Python:How to append a certain item in a list in a text file

Tags: list, python-3.x, append, text-files

How would you change a certain item in a list in a text file?
If you have a text file set out as such:
email,password
email,password
email,password
How could you search the email and then change the password for that email?
I know this is very vague so I am happy to answer any questions about it.

Comment: You can’t change the text file directly when the new password is longer than the old one. You could read the whole file into a dictionary, change the value (password) of the key (email) and write the dictionary back to the file. By the way: such an email-password-list should never exist! It is highly insecure in every environment.

Comment: @Marvo dont worry it isnt holding any secure information, just a project I am working on , is there no way at all just to append a certain item in a list?

Comment: You could use a list instead of a dictionary, of course.

Comment: @Marvo This is the error I get with that : for e,p in dictionary.items(): NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the password file into a dictionary and replaces or adds an email-passord-combination:

```
dictionary = {}

with open("password.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        e, p = line.strip().split(", ")
        dictionary[e] = p

email = input("Enter email: ")
password = input("Enter new password: ")

dictionary[email] = password

with open("password.txt","w") as file:
    for e,p in dictionary.items():
        print(e,p,sep=", ",file=file)
```

The password file could be this one:

```
you@example.com, old_password
noone@example.com, uzt(647zt2(/r
lastone@email.com, zzzzzappp!
youtoo@example.com, password
xkcd@example.com, correct horse battery staple
weall@example.com, topsecret
```

Comment: This is the error I get with that : for e,p in dictionary.items():
NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined

Comment: Did you delete the first line?